# Writing an output on an input line in Cobol

Tags: cobol

`Customer ID                  Name                 Order Date`

......................................................................................`Year  Month  Day`

`123456789                    Johnny Smith`

`234567890                    Mary Campbell`

`345678901                    Ed Bilewicz`

`456789012                    Tim Rahmen`

`567890123                    Cheryl Graham`

`678901234                    Robert Thomas McGill`

So i have a .dat file that i am working on. I was provided with the ID's and the Names only and have managed to format the .out file like this (that didn't appear to be an issue). What i would like to know is how would i go about adding the Day, Month, and Year to this .out file while keeping them on the same lines as the names and ID's.
I'm really new to Cobol so theres a lot of terms i don't understand yet. i tried writing variables in my inline-file (eg il-id), assigning the number with a move command then transfer out to a variable in my outline-file (ol-id) then write the outline-file but it didn't appear to work. though it's not out of the realm of possibility that i simply did it wrong. 
Any help with what im supposed to do would be very appreciated. and again, im new to this so the less complex terms the easier i might be able to understand.
thanks so much.

Comment: What have you tried ???. Normally with Cobol you would setup a line-record with all the fields you want. Then you  would move the data to the output record and write it

Comment: So i set up an in-line, it reads the characters then i have a 01 input-line with 05's to declare and place the individual pieces. 
then i've got my outline that is basically the same thing except i added fillers to format.
i also have a move command to move the in-data variables into the ol-data variables. After that i write it to the file. Basically what i've tried to do is add them using that same logic. have a variable in in il and the ol, declare in the procedure division, move to il- data variable, move to ol-data variable then write it out....if that makes any sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually Data definition concept in COBOL look like flat file class associates to serialization or entity class associates to persistent mapping in modern programming language.

Here is a sample of Data Definition (in DATA DIVISION):

```
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
...
02 OL-ID.
   05 CUSTOMER-ID    PIC X(10).
   05 CUSTOMER-NAME  PIC X(20).
   05 ORDER-DATE.
      10 YEAR   PIC X(4).
      10 FILLER PIC X(1) VALUE '-'.
      10 MONTH  PIC X(2).
      10 FILLER PIC X(1) VALUE '-'.
      10 DAY    PIC X(2).
```

Hope this helps.